# Building front-end angular application using npm grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, npm, gruntjs

This is the first question i am asking, please excuse me if it is not clear.
i am also new to building an application, i am building angular js application using grunt.

my question is i have done build using grunt tasks like below. so now i have all minified css and java script files in my "build" folder. while deploying app("build") in server.
1) do i need to have all node modules in "build"
2) if yes how can i get into build
3) what exactly "build" or "dist" should contain?

```
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint','concat','ngAnnotate','uglify','htmlmin','copy','connect','watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Grunt is a task runner which will make lots of your work very easy, like concatination, minification etc.

As a standard there will be three folder for this process
 - build
 - dist
 - src

**src:** This folder will contain all your source files, this is where developers write code. Files in this folder will be organised for the easiness of development and to module structure.

We have to deploy our code to server which is concatenated, minified, annotated, etc. for better performance and various reasons specific to projects. Grunt task are used to convert the files in src folder to deployable code.

**dist:** This the folder where all the files which is the output of the grunt tasks resides. This is the folder which will go to the server.

**build** This folder will have all files which is used for grunt tasks resides. eg: grunt.js, package.json, node_modules, etc.

only **dist** folder will go to server. nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Node modules are just used by the development server and all the client side tooling etc. The build version will have something along the lines of scripts.js(your JavaScript files i.e the angular app) vendor.js(all the angular libraries) index.html and some css files.